# How to convert this AppInventor Blocks to Kotlin Code? Any Idea

Tags: kotlin, app-inventor

Hi there I want to convert those blocks from the AppInventor project to Android Studio Project Using Kotiln as my programing language but I am very new to android development can anyone help me with that?

[image]

What this app does is opening webview and reload my webpage URL at a randomly generated time.

What I tried so far!

```
package com.technosoftkpk.y_view

import android.os.Bundle
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val myWebView: WebView = findViewById(R.id.webview)
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(WebViewClient())
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://technosoft.pk")
        val webSettings = myWebView.settings
        webSettings.displayZoomControls = true
        webSettings.javaScriptEnabled = true

        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work? This will randomly wait between 0 and 5 seconds. (Add the code at the end of `onCreate`):

```
import kotlin.concurrent.thread
import kotlin.random.Random
```

```
thread {
    while (true) {
        Thread.sleep(Random.nextLong(5000))
        runOnUiThread { myWebView.reload() }
    }
}
```

This might look complicated, but we need to make a new thread to avoid blocking the UI thread and allowing user input. But then the reloading needs to happen on the UI thread again. An alternative would be to use `postDelayed`.

Comment: Added like this https://ibb.co/hKLWKLv   but the app is crashing. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @ElizabethHarper Put the whole `thread { ... }` block _after_ the line `webSettings.javaScriptEnabled = true`, don't move your original code

Comment: Still not working app is not opening at all. Here is my logcat  https://wtools.io/paste-code/b4qZ and here is my code https://wtools.io/paste-code/b4ra.

Comment: @ElizabethHarper I think you accidentally deleted the line "package com.technosoftkpk.y_view" on top. Either way I think that message is unrelated to my code snippet.

Comment: Yes, you are right the problem is I didn't include the package name now it's working fine. Thanks for your valuable time! Peace :-)

Comment: I also want to display the random time generated by your code snippet in a toast so the user knows how much time they wait for the page to auto refresh. Any solution will be highly appreciated.

Comment: No worries. I think you should be able to do that with Kotlin experience, but it would go along the lines of: `val t = Random.nextLong(5000); Toast.makeText(this, "Wait $t milliseconds", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); Thread.sleep(t)`